# Adding meta tags to solidJs application using @solidjs/meta

Tags: typescript

I defined my index.tsx according to the documentation but I'm getting type error. I'm using typescript , what is the type for Meta tags.

`index.tsx`

```
/* @refresh reload */
import { render,renderToString  } from 'solid-js/web';
import { Router } from '@solidjs/router';
import { MetaProvider, renderTags } from '@solidjs/meta';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const tags = []; // mutated during render so you can include in server-rendered template later

const app = renderToString(() =>
  <MetaProvider tags={tags}>
    <App />
  </MetaProvider>
);
```

ERROR

`Variable 'tags' implicitly has an 'any[]' type`

When I define the type as string i get this error :

`The expected type comes from property 'tags' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { tags?: TagDescription[] | undefined; } & { children?: Element; }'`

Comment: For this kind of work, I recommend using IntelliSense if you are using VSCode or LSP if you are using another editor (such as Neovim)